# array_combine returning one result only

Tags: php, arrays, drop-down-menu

I am trying to output the values of an array into a drop down menu.

I am using Pear PHP to get the data.

If I concatenate the strings all the data is there, however the values are not set accordingly.

I tried to use `array_combine` to set the keys as values in the drop down. This works, however only one result is returned (when it should be 3). With the concatenation the three results are all shown with the wrongs keys set though.

```
DO_Common::DebugLevel(1);
$stDO = DO_Common::factory('SoftwareTypes');
$lmDO = DO_Common::factory('LicenseMethods');
$tDO = DO_Common::factory('sldSoftwareType');

//            
$stDO->selectAdd();
$stDO->selectAdd('Title, Method, sldSoftwareType.Type, SoftwareTypes.ID');
$stDO->joinAdd($lmDO);
$stDO->joinAdd($tDO);
$stDO->whereAdd("SoftwareTypes.Flag <> 1");


$stDO->find();

$lmst[] = null;
$keys = null;
$arr = null;

while ($stDO->fetch())
  {
    $keys = $stDO->ID . " | " ;
    $text = $stDO->Title . " | " . $stDO->Method . " | " .$stDO->Type; 

    $arr = array($keys =>  $text);

     $lmst = $arr;
  }
```

Why is array_combine only returning one value?

DropDown creation Code (using HTML QuickForms):

$ddlSoftwareType = $form->addElement('select', 'ddlSoftwareType', 'Software Type', $lmst, array('id' => "SoftwareTypeList", 'orderBy' => "Type", "OnChange" => "GetDetails();"));

Expected Output (should be Value as key, and 3 columns combined as string):

Dropdown Item:(ID AS VALUE) Title | Method | Type

---

Dropdown Item2:(ID AS VALUE) Title | Method | Type

---

Expected (with more items in dropdown - same as shown in the table):

[image]

Current output:
[image]

I have tried array_combine before, with same results.

Comment: POst your array structure along with expected output

Comment: also post your expected result

Comment: Where are you doing an array_combine()?

Comment: @DeepKakkar Done. Posted expected output.

Comment: Whats the values within array can you post that values@Brian

Comment: @Uchiha The values should be set in the while loop: `$stDO->Title`  , `$stDO->Method` ,`$stDO->Type` .. thus why I tried `$arr = array($keys =>  $text)`;

Comment: Even  though its really unclear

Comment: @Uchiha They are just three columns concatenated to each other. ($stDO->Title is a row for example). I am using the PEAR framework to get data but I don't think it is relevant to the question.

Comment: Try `$lmst[$key] = $text` @Brian

Comment: Posting it as an answer @Brian

Answer (score 1):

use like this `array_push($lmst, $arr);` instead of   `$lmst = $arr;`

Comment: Nope, it returns 3 items but they are all called 'Array'

Comment: what exactly you want at that dropdown

Comment: where would you create this drop down, show the code of that

Comment: I created it using HTML_QuickForms:

Comment: i dont have idea on HTML QuickForms